# How can I get started in WvW?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Every time I've entered WvW I've been hopelessly lost and confused. I read all the tutorials and listened to all the NPCs and read the wiki articles but I've no idea where I'm actually supposed to *start*.

What are some activities I can do in WvW as a noob and a solo player?

Comment: I would say the easiest way to get into WvW is to look for the orange crossed sword icons on your map. Try to go to one of those which means a battle is taking place involving your server. When you locate one of these sometimes you will find it is a small scrap and othertimes you will find it is something much bigger. By findiing the combat your are discovering the way WvW works. Sometimes your team may be on the defense, or heading to a camp. Follow the battles and WvW will explain itself natrually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, you should look the map for a commander if any is present. If so, he should be giving the orders (if he's a good commander and not just someone who wants to show his shining blue icon).

If no commander is present, people usually gather in "buses of player", in order to raid places with a massive force. It's usually a good group to learn WvW as well as doing things with lot of successes.

Eventually, you will want to do something on your own. If so, be sure to bring some friends along in your party. There are some thing a small group (or even a single person) can do:

- Raiding Supply Camps (be sure to avoid camps that has been taken within the last 5 minutes, as the Supervisor will have a strong buff)
- Raiding Towers with a ram (requires at least 4 person to be able to built it if untouched by the enemy)
- Scouting: intelligence is a need for every strategist. Being able to provide insight on the enemy progress will help the leaders to choose the right course of action.
- Raiding Keeps: there are times when a prolonged battle takes place between two (or even three) large forces on a map. And during these phases, a well organised group may be able to quietly gain control of a keep. Of course, you will need rams and thus enough supply. But I recall one time where I took Shadaran Hills with only 4 players of my guild. Of course, don't expect to succeed this unless you get some luck (We also were prepared to be wiped out before reaching the second door, but seems they were so occupied by the main battles that they did not take attention to us :P)

Don't feel oppressed by the player giving orders on the /map, you can contribute to it yourself. Don't hesitate to ask questions too, many players will be kind enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

For starters in WvW I suggest you to queue your server's name to "borderlands" and as soon as you get in, follow higher level players who have experience playing WvW.

If you start alone or are lost, read the world chat and see where other players are calling for groups/reinforcements. Although I'am mostly a PvE player, I played a few WvW rounds and over time you will get the hang of it. There are some similar events in WvW to the PvE events. Just follow your teammates, attend events, protect, and capture.

The best way to not get lost or confused is to pay attention to the world chat, where teammates will often tell you the points/objectives needed throughout the game. If you keep queuing up everyday, after sometime you will get the hang of it.

Comment: You can also explore like the regular world. There are Vistas and local points located through out the map. Some will be hard to get as some points are captured by enemy servers. You can also find many mats such as iron, trees, and gatherings for your Disciplines.